# PDP 8 instruction set length comparison

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, machine-code, instruction-set

Comparing difference between 8080 and PDP-8.

- 8080 supports instructions of variable length, but does PDP-8?
- Does PDP-8 support instructions of variable length?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.faqs.org/faqs/dec-faq/pdp8/section-3.html  and eat you heart out, with all you've wanted to know about the PDP-8 instruction set.  Most instructions are only 1 word long, some instructions are 2 words long.

Answer (score 2):

No, all basic PDP-8 instructions were 12 bits long.

If you added the EAE option (Extended Arithmetic Element) to add hardware multiply/divide, the address following a MUY or DVI held an address, and the address following a SHL, ASR, or LSR held a shift count, but those were such an exception that they were not considered multi-word instructions.